# Ubuntu server "sudo" error AWS EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sudo, sudoers

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on Amazon's EC2 and i logged in with the default user "ubuntu" the issue here is that I can't run commands as a **sudeor** .

When i try to run commands with **sudo** i get :

> sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
>
> sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
>
> sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

I  searched everywhere for help and all suggested solutions failed to solve the problem.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It`s a bit lengthy procedure, but I got a way out. The ultimate objective is to gain access to root user. 
Step 1- Add a new user that does not need .ppk key to login. 
1. Firstly stop your faulty instance and make a copy of the same EC2 instance.
2. Now in the AWS console, you will see a "Volumne" tab on the left hand side. Detach the volume of the faulty instance and attach with the new instance. 
3. Now mount this newly attach drive in the new instance and add a new user into it.
4. Simply now create a new user and set permission that user don`t need a .ppk key file to login.

Step 2: Getting root access
1. Once you login with this new user created, you have to simply type "su" command. You will be asked to enter the password of the new user.
2. Enter password and now you will be a root user. You don`t need sudo anymore.